# How to detect on client side if FusionMap tiles cached and ready to be displayed?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

My webpage displays runtime generated FusionTables data on a Google Map.

The problem is: when you create a FusionTable with geometry type column and display it for the first time, Google has to load all related map tiles in its server side cache. This takes a while - sometimes 2-3 sec, sometimes 15 -20 sec. 
During caching, the map should display a grey overlay saying "Data may still be loading...". I'd like to avoid this screen, because it's very buggy. Sometimes the overlay is displayed, sometimes not.

I'm looking for a way to detect if all map tiles cached so that i can display the map to the user.

I already tried to refresh the map tiles periodically, but this will give me no feedback when to stop refreshing:

```
    $("img[src*='googleapis']").each(function(){
       $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src")+"&"+(new Date()).getTime());
    });
```

For this reason I'm looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: simply there's no way to do it as of now.

As a sidenote: I'd never advise anyone to think about using FusionTables to display dynamically generated geographic data. It's not designed that way. Only use FT if you have a somewhat static dataset that changes rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your geographic data. The message appears when the server-side process misses a deadline for serving the map tile in a reasonable time. By reducing the complexity of the polygons, you're much more likely to not see the "Data may still be loading...." message tiles.

You can reduce the complexity in two ways:  reduce the number of vertices (points) that define the polygons, and reduce the precision of the lat/long locations.

Please also note as an FYI that as the exact same map gets called again and again by different viewers, the process results are cached server-side and the message becomes *much* less likely to appear, and then usually due to public cacheing.

-Rebecca

Comment: Public caching won't help me because every user generates the map for himself. The generated map is not visible to other users and it is very unlikely that the same user generates the same map twice. That is exactly my problem, i can't avoid caching that's why i'm looking for ways to detect if it is finished or still in progress.